# How to organize "master" data VS "working" data in MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net-core

I have this survey software that I'm writing and I'm wondering what would be the best design for my requirement.

I'm going to simplify it as best as I can.

I have these entities:

```
class Survey {
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<SurveyQuestion> SurveyQuestions { get; set }
}

class SurveyQuestion {
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public Guid SurveyId {get;set;}
    public string Question { get; set;}
    public string Answer {get;set;}
}
```

A user obviously can design surveys and its questions, but also can start an "instance" of a survey.

When an instance is started, I'd would like it to stay as it is and not change if the "master" definition of the survey/questions is changed afterwards.

So I thought of having an entity like this:

```
class SurveyInstance {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public Guid SurveyId {get;set;}
}
```

When it is created, I would create an SQL schema with the returned `Id` of the created instance, then create both `Survey` and `SurveyQuestion` tables under that new schema and insert the relevant data in them.

That way, when a user resumes the survey, there are no risk of breaking changes if the "master" data changes in the meantime.

Obviously, the `Answer` property of `SurveyQuestion` will only hold a value when the row is present in a table under a schema other than `dbo`.

When the survey instance is deleted, I would drop all the tables under its schema, then drop the schema altogether.

Are there other approaches, pitfalls, problems I'm missing ?

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with this design? Questions asking for general feedback about a design are usually closed as being opinion-based or needing focus. You have a lot of good information in your question, but I don't see an engineering problem to solve.

Comment: Well, I guess it can be closed because other people's opinion is exactly what I'm looking for. I was just trying to see if there were any other designs that would be better than mine.

Comment: Unfortunately opinion-based questions do not fit the Q&A style of this community. You might try [chat] or more general forums on other sites.

Comment: Well, I actually see a few specific questions you could ask in this question which might be answered in a non-opinionated manner. Not sure if you really want to ask them, though. You could, for example, ask for a design which avoids to create and drop tables while the program is running. Or for a design which avoids to repeat the storage of the same question text for each person answering the survey, while you still have questions "frozen" once the survey was started.

Comment: Why is `Answer` within `SurveyQuestion`? Since a single frozen question set might be asked of several respondents, wouldn't it make more sense to delete that attribute, and define a 3rd level of master-detail named `SurveyResponse`? It would hold a reference to a frozen set of questions, and would support storing the answers of several respondents.

Comment: Have you considered nosql instead?

Answer (score 0):

## CoW

This sounds like a
[copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)
situation.

You have an evolving table such as `SurveyQuestion`,
and you'd like for various callers to take a reference
to its current snapshot.

For simplicity I will assume the `Survey` table is append-only.
That is, we INSERT, we don't DELETE, and we never assign
a new `name` to an existing survey.
With these restrictions we can still capture much
of the intended business use case.

The `SurveyQuestion` detail table is quite mutable, supporting Q's & A's
that authors keep editing / deleting / adding. There's a
[FK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)
relationship to `Survey`.

Invent a third level of detail, a `SurveyAnswer` table,
with FK to `SurveyQuestion`.

Now deleting a `Survey` or `SurveyQuestion` row
will cascade through to one or two levels of detail records.
Avoid making UPDATEs to those two tables,
preferring to INSERT new rows when e.g. correcting a typo.
That way existing references are associated with frozen unchanging text.
Feel free to run a daily cron job that deletes master rows
having ancient timestamps or zero child detail rows.